# MongoDB - How to perform joins as in relational databases

Tags: mongodb, nosql

As you may have guessed, I am from the RDBMS background.

I have made a document model in MongoDB. The simple representation would be like:

Collection `users`

```json
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "name": "Simon",
  "photo": "https://...jpg"
}
```

Collection: `Posts`

```json
{
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "author": ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>),
  "likes": [ ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>), ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>) ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "author": ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>),
      "content": "Hi everyone!",
      "likes": [ ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>), ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>) ],
      "replies": [
         {
            "author": ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>),
            "content": "Hi everyone!",
            "likes": [ ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>), ObjectId(<AdIdFromUsers>) ],
         }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have read from mongodb docs that it's okay to use [Manual Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) in most cases.

But my question here is, How can I optimize this to make hundreds of requests to the database to get information about a post? Like:

1. Get the post document first
2. Then loop through the comments and replies and get author info
3. Loop through likes and get each user

Please feel free to correct me if I'm taking the wrong approach

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it is totally normal in my opinion. I am doing it the same way. In my back-end when I want to get multiple sub documents from my actual document, I go through a `for` loop, collect the info, store it in a array and then return the response to the user.

Here are some advantages:

- You don't have to create a separate collection for every type of document you have
- From my knowledge it is somewhat slower but should definitely do the job
- You can keep all the info in one place

Comment: I would like to make it as fast as possible, because if it's not the right method, the whole app would slow down when I release to the public... I'll probably be receiving lots of traffic...

Comment: I mean the slow part is when you get all the data, then you push it to the array and then send it to the user. When dealing with large amounts of data, I think yeah you should consider using separate collections for each model. One way you can do that easily is to use mongoose. You'll be able to find a subdocument just like this: `findOne({"posts._id": some_id})`